# How to move Local PHP App DB Records to Live DB Records when Connect Internet

Tags: php, laravel

Now I, Working in Billing Application using Laravel Framework. When User System Connected to the Internet. Local application db Records automatically Updated to the Live Site Records. How can Implement this Process

Answer (score 0):

Well, That will require lots of thing to take care of.

**First**
Check if you're connected to internet using some php scripts like this

```
<?php
function is_connected()
{
    $connected = @fsockopen("www.some_domain.com", 80); 
                                    //website, port  (try 80 or 443)
    if ($connected){
        $is_conn = true; //action when connected
        fclose($connected);
    }else{
        $is_conn = false; //action in connection failure
    }
    return $is_conn;

}
?>
```

**Second**

If your billing application is used by you only then it is simple, to achieve what you want.
In this scenario,

1. Keep a log of each and every query you're doing on your local machine.
2. If connected to internet, run those queries on remote machine using some remote connection to that database. then clear the log.

If your billing application is used by more than one users, then chances of conflicts will increase.
For Example:
*You've deleted some record and another user updated that record.*

Do let me know which one you need ? If you need the second approach, I'll update the answer.